# Java Get name of File in FileWriter

Tags: java, arrays, file, filenames, filewriter

I was wondering, in Java is it at all possible to pull the File object or at least the name the file used in a FileWriter as a string? I looked through the documentation and as far as I can tell it isn't possible, but I'm often wrong on this stuff.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Its rare to be in a situation where you are handed a FileWriter but dont know where you are writing.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, you have `FileWritter` reference but don't have `File` ?

Comment: Simply put: no.  FileWriter doesn’t have any methods at all, in fact, except for those inherited from other classes.

Comment: My code needs to be really efficient with regards to what it is doing. It's cycling hundreds of thousands of times, so I pass it a FileWriter instead of a File so i don't need to create a new FileWriter object every cycle. Theoretically i could also pass it the File as another parameter, however i'd only use it to grab the name, which seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: I suggest you use a wrapper class which contains a reference to both the Writer and the File. Probably also improves the readability of the code. Alternatively, you could store the File path in a ThreadLocal (in case your app is multithreaded) or a static field. Not very elegant, but it would probably work.

Comment: Oh that's a good idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend from `FileWriter` class, provide a getter for file/filename:

```
public class MyFileWriter extends FileWriter {
    private File file;
    private boolean append = false;

    public MyFileWriter(File file) throws IOException {
        this(file, false);
    }
    public MyFileWriter(File file, boolean append) throws IOException {
        super(file, append);
        this.file = file;
        this.append = append;
    }
    public MyFileWriter(String fileName) throws IOException {
        this(new File(fileName));
    }
    public MyFileWriter(String fileName, boolean append) throws IOException {
        this(new File(fileName), append);
    }
// getters/setters
}
```

Comment: Oh that's a clever solution. I like that!